# Strange logic task from an old exam - proof required

Tags: calculus, logic

*I hope this is the correct section, if not I apologize and I'd like to know where to ask a question like that!*

I got a logic task from an old exam and I don't understand it. I will explain as much as I can so hopefully you can help me understanding.

Actually this whole thing is what an arithmetic-logic-unit does and $BA$ decides if the operation is arithmetic (sub, add, mul, div..) or logic (invert, and, or, notand...)

So if $BA = 0$ then it's arithmetic and if $BA=1$ it's logic operation. In this case it's arithmetic operation, subtraction to be more precise.

Logic function is given:

$$Q = \left( (S_{3} \wedge A \wedge B) \vee (S_{2}\wedge A \wedge \bar{B})\vee (S_{1} \wedge \bar{A} \wedge B) \vee (S_{0} \wedge \bar{A} \wedge \bar{B})  \right ) \Leftrightarrow (BA \vee c_{-1})$$

**Prove that if $BA= 0$ and $S=0110$ then a subtraction will be executed, so: $Q = A-B-1+c_{-1}$**

$S=0110$ means that $S_{3}= 0$, $S_{2}= 1$, $S_{1}= 1$, $S_{0}= 0$

We are allowed to assume that $Q = (A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C)$

---

So I have started by putting each $S$, and $BA$ into the function and get:

$$Q = \left ((A \wedge \bar{B}) \vee (\bar{A} \wedge B) \right) \Leftrightarrow (0 \vee c_{-1})$$

Now after forming, I get:

$$Q= \left ( (A \vee \bar{A}) \wedge (\bar{B} \wedge B) \right ) \Leftrightarrow c_{-1}$$

$$Q = \left (1 \wedge 0 \right ) \Leftrightarrow c_{-1}$$

$$Q = 0 \Leftrightarrow c_{-1}$$

This doesn't seem to help me at all and seems for away from what I was supposed to prove...

Any ideas how I could prove this task correctly? I was on the right track at all?

I have added a table. We have $S = 0110$ and $BA = 0$.
This would be line 7 in the table on the very right side. Maybe this helps? And table says $A-B-1+c_{-1}$ which is actually the thing we want prove here, that $Q$ equals this.

[image]

Comment: I don't spot where you tell us "what I was supposed to prove", nor have you asked a question.  I don't understand the proposition "We are allowed to assume that $Q = (A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C)$".  A chain of bi-implications might make sense in a proof or shorthand for pairwise mutual logical equivalence, but what would it mean that $Q$ "equals" such a collection of bi-implications?

Comment: My question is "how can I prove this?". I have found this task on our university website, some kind of help service from students for students. And there it was written like that (the unclear part for you): q = (a <-> b <-> c). I have replaced these signs with an equivalence symbol hoping to make it more clear - but I might have misunderstood them and even made it more unclear I see.. : /

Comment: Prove that if $BA = 0$ and $S=0110$, $Q$ will equal $A-B-1+c_{-1}$

Comment: But we have no definition of $A$, $B$, or $c_{-1}$ in terms of $BA$ or $S$ to work with.  Apparently you do, in view of your deducing something about $Q$.

Comment: I have added a table. We have $S = 0110$ and $BA = 0$.
This would be line 7 in the table on the very right side. Maybe this helps? And table says $A-B-1+c_{-1}$ which is actually the thing we want prove here, that $Q$ equals this.

Comment: I don't think your "logic task" is amenable to much reasoned mathematical argument.  Taking your table at face value, it tells you what you say "I was supposed to prove".  Again, without giving some mathematical or logical definitions of $A,B,c_{-1}$, no one can "prove" anything about them in relation to $BA = 0$ and $S=0110$.

Comment: Alright, I have described as much as I could. Are you saying the task is unclear / doesn't make sense? If that's the case, I'm happy too and conclude that the student who "released" the exam (his version) did a mistake somewhere / forgot something. Because I don't understand it as well.

Comment: For future reference, when you ask Questions here, you are the expert about what you ask.  If your Readers cannot rely on you to know what is being asked, we also cannot rely on you to tell whether an Answer is correct.